# Removing a killer bee hive?

Tags: insects, bee-attractive

This morning I found a small bee hive in open space hanging low from a tree here in California, which is one sign they're killer bees. Their wings look smaller than other bees here, but experts say the only way to know for certain is under a microscope. I can't find any info on what people are supposed to do. Is it my responsibility to have them removed and killed or is it okay to let them be? I've told everyone about it so they'll stay clear, and our cat shouldn't be a problem. The only thing I'm concerned about is aiding the spread of killer bees. Also I hear they kill and take over normal honey bee hives.

Comment: Ask your local apiaries or bee associations to capture the bees for you. Your local university extension should be able to direct you into the right way. Besides it is unsure if they are "Africanized bees" or not and bee club are always looking for new colonies to start. If they are not "Africanized bees" someone will be willing to take the bees off your hands for free.

Comment: Ken is right. But please no spraying by yourself.  Your local University Cooperative Extension Service will find a professional to come out and do a professional ID.  They'll be the ones that need to educate you.  Killing any bees/wasps/hornets is contraindicated as you know we are having a big problem with bee deaths.  And those 'Bee Clubs' will beat a path to your door to help you!  Glad you asked!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask your local [University Cooperative Extension Service](http://ucanr.edu/) for assistance. They will be able to point you in the correct way to go about removing the bees. Identification of what species of [bees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_bee) is a must. They may or may not be "Africanized bees", commonly known as "killer bees". The University Cooperative Extension Service can send a professional to your home for ID purposes and can inform you on the right course of action is needed.

If the bees are healthy honeybees, you will have local bee clubs begging you to let them take the bees off your hands. Simply ask them.